# Remove artificially generated words from a word list in Linux?

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, grep, generic-list

Hello everyone and good day!
I have the following question: I have a word list that consists of normal words as well as artificially generated words.

example:

```
Ford
09mKGmaePnCmjkxm
Opel
0AACyvG0FtRHAU7i
Audi
0AR6V7cCy2phgXcv
BMW
0bDOlBY5VGAe5Vai
Alfa-Romeo
Mercedes
Pegout-323
0BDTwSCCrCy4VgEc
0cmolI8g4CerXKaH
0dL2m36014PmOetH
0dqjCZU7ZeRuovFF
0ekelbAnWcGC1c7n
Lada 2109
Lada 2106
0ER4tS8jhESXuISp
0Gao8qHgbEyZ06Bh
0j1pjZBAW2avxU6Z
0j5zBVhdPDyaVoZL
Toyouta
0Jn0qoKdnM6neGdx
0KlzXttiw81AvU2C
0kXzuEtHxiWfECw7
mitsubisi
0l8qW9Uv0V1DZPei
0LJQxUNuEp42txme
jeep
0m8G1GUytcETbtWv
0MexVW3TQ2sRqLjr
```

I want to remove all artificially generated words from this list.
I have converted such words to REGEX and saved them in a new file "Generic.txt":

```
[0-9][0-9][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]
[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][a-z]
[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][a-z][A-Z][a-z][0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z]
[0-9][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z]
[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][0-9][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z]
[0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z]
[0-9][a-z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z]
[0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z]
[0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z]
[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z]
[0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z][0-9][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][a-z]
[0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z]
[0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z]
[0-9][A-Z][a-z][0-9][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z]
[0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z]
[0-9][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][0-9]
[0-9][a-z][0-9][a-z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][a-z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z]
[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]
[0-9][a-z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z]
[0-9][A-Z][a-z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z][a-z]
```

Now I want to delete from the word list "base.txt" all words that match this regex. They can also be larger than 16 characters!
I use the following command:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -F -f generic.txt base.txt > test.txt
```

Unfortunately I get no results, but also no error messages. What am I doing wrong?
Basically I want grep to check the file "base.txt" for every line from the file "generic.txt" and extract these lines into a new file.

The following list should remain at the end:

```
Ford
Opel
Audi
BMW
Alfa-Romeo
Mercedes
Pegout-323
Lada 2109
Lada 2106
Toyouta
mitsubisi
jeep
```

TIA
Sergio

Comment: Are the grossly misspelled car brands examples of machine-generated text, or the opposite?

Comment: All the obviously machine-generated tokens begin with 0 and have a fixed length; isn't that enough to exclude them? `grep -Ev '^0[A-Za-z0-9]{15}$' base.txt` (or maybe remove the initial 0 and change the repetition count from 15 to 16 to capture all strings without spaces or punctuation which are exactly 16 characters long).

Comment: I need solution for strictly defined regex lines. There are lines that also contain [a-z] or [A-Z] as a start. Or machine-generated text with more as 15 characters... :-(

Comment: "grep -v -E -f generic.txt base.txt > new.txt" Works!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate error is that the `-F` option disables regular expressions entirely, and requires the text to match the pattern literally. (So for example `[0-9]` matches the literal string `[0-9]` and no other strings.)

Probably a better approach entirely is to try to generalize this absurd list of patterns to a single pattern, or a very small list of patterns. How did you come up with this list?

For example

```
grep -E '^[A-Za-z0-9]{16}$' base.txt
```

seems to extract only the (apparent) generated patterns in your example.

Comment: If you want 16 or more, change `{16}` to `{16,}` or perhaps specify in more detail which string lengths are interesting (I'm guessing maybe 16, 20, 24... or perhaps multiples of 8 or 16?)

Comment: Thank you! This help me. -F and regex-problem... I don't know this. :-)

Comment: But then why did you specify the `-F` option in the first place?

Comment: This is not quite the solution I needed, but I now have a few more ideas. The same command to search for several words from a list is nevertheless
 grep -F -f 1.txt

Or grep -i 'abc|abcd|abcde|abcdef

Comment: No, `grep -f filename` is the syntax to read patterns from a file, and the unrelated `-F` option switches from regex patterns to literal strings (aka trad `fgrep`; similarly `-E` switches to `egrep` semantics). Maybe you also want to look at `-x` which requires the entire input line (rather than a substring) to match (one of the) pattern(s).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the definition of a "word", meaning why should `Ford` be a valid word while e.g. `F0rd` is not? That said, for your given list, you could use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[- ]\w+)?$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7W8RmZ/1/).

---

Another solution would be to emphasize that a word cannot start with a digit, thus anything that starts with a digit does not contain valid words:

```
^[0-9].{15}$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^.+
```

See [**another demo for this one on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7W8RmZ/2/).

Comment: Hi Jan, Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for how to delete all lines from one list (which are predefined by regex) in another list.